# Implementation of Newton's Method in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to implement Newton's Method in clojure to solve the equation f(x)=0. Function takes these arguments: f(function) f'(function's derivative) n(# of iterations)=10 and x0(initial guess)=10.

```
 (defn newtons-method [f f' n x0]
     (if (<= (f x0))
         n
         (newtons-method f f' (- x0 (/ (f x0) (f' x0))) (+ n 1)))
     )
```

I'm getting an output of 10, but instead want the final solution of x and result of f(x) and I know 10 is wrong, because my function f and its derivative give the correct answer, so I assume I'm messing up somewhere in the iterations

Comment: What is that `(<= (f x0))`?

Comment: It seems one parameter is missing in `<=`.  It should be something like `(<= (f x0) err)`  where `err` is the acceptable margin of error.  `<=` on single argument will return true and this explains why you never get the correct answer.

Comment: You might have your last two  arguments, `n` and `x0`,  reversed in the inner call to `newtons-method`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to have at least two issues.
Firstly, your conditional will always return true (assuming `(f x0)` returns a numeric value), so that is likely not what you want to do.

Also, in order to properly implement recursive functions in clojure, you should have a look at [recur](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur), otherwise you could run into stack overflows (unlikely in this particular case, but still)

Another minor thing, instead of doing `(+ n 1)`, it's idiomatic to use `(inc n)`